# PHP shows up blank inf IE & Firefox but not Safari

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox

I am new to php & have a simple "tell a friend" code. A popup is suppose to come up & show that the message has been sent to the friend. This works great in Safari, however it shows up blank in IE & Firefox.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "speedyblindsdfw@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Check this site out!"; 

function died($error) {
    //error code 
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }

  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['senders_email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
  }

$email_from = $_POST['senders_email']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}

 function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "I was on this site today & thought you would be interested.";
$email_message .= "\nwww.primaresidential.com\n\n";
$email_message .= "Dear " .clean_string($email). ",";       
$email_message .= "\nYour friend, " .clean_string($email_from). " had linked";
$email_message .= "our site to your email, we hope you enjoy our site as much as they did!"; 
$email_message .= "\n\nPrima Residential Services."; 

//email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();    
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
 @mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 ?>

  <!----HTML CODE------>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>PrimaResidential Serivces- Emailer</title> 
       <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/style.css";</style>  
       <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/style.css";</style>


      </head>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="boxbg all-round" id="page-container-Popup">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><center>
        <h2>Your email was successfully sent.</h2><br>
        <br><h3>Thank you for spreading the word.<br>
           <font size="1"> Be sure to check your email in the next 2-3 business days for a little surprise.</font></h3>
        <br/></center>

        </div>
        <a href="javascript:window.close()">Close Window</a>      


     </body>
     </html>

     <?php
      }
     ?>
```

Please let me know if you see what I did wrong or what I need to add. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You did not include a `<body>` tag, so the browser is forced to guess. You are also importing the same stylesheet twice. It's possible that the excessive amount of `<br>` tags is pushing the actual content off the bottom of the screen, or out of the element if it has `overflow:hidden`. Overall, you have a large number of issues that I suggest you fix and see if that helps any.

Comment: I appreciate it. I will try to fix those & see if that works!

Comment: It was the <body> tag, gosh! here I am thinking it was my noob php self & its really a missed html! *smack forehead* Thank you!